I am looking for a way to delete all printers except some from the txt file using a powershell script
This works:
@echo off
wmic printer where "NOT name like 'print1' AND NOT name like 'print 2'" delete
exit

But how do I download a list of printer names from a text file, since I need to delete more than 100 printers

get-printer and remove-printer

Windows ships with a PrintManagement module that allows you to enumerate and remove printers from PowerShell without calling wmic.exe:
# read list of excluded printers into memory from file
$excludedPrinters = Get-Content path\to\list\of\excluded_printers.txt

# enumerate printers, filter against list, and then remove the rest
Get-Printer |Where-Object Name -notin $excludedPrinters |Remove-Printer -WhatIf

Remove the -WhatIf flag for the removal to take effect
